# Unable to find package 'pythonx86' via nuget

Tags: python, c, visual-studio-code, nuget, cpython

I downloaded the CPython source code from the CPython GitHub repo and ran `.\PCBuild\build.bat -p x64 -c Debug` in the command line of VScode. Inside `.\cpython\PCBuild\` it consists `build.bat`. As I wanted to make a compiled CPython binary, executing `build.bat` will create `.\PCBuild\amd64\python_d.exe`.When that .bat file gets executed it says,

```
Installing Python via nuget...
Feeds used:

Installing package 'pythonx86' to 'D:\CHETAN\cpython\externals'
```

and print the error message as :

```
Unable to find package 'pythonx86'
```

Can anyone have a fix for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build the source code with the latest Visual Studio.

Visual Studio 2022 Community can work well:

[image]

The external folder only contains following packages:
[image]

You can also use `dumpbin` to check `python_d.exe` dependents.
[image]